# scope of the program: how to keep track of a variable in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, scope

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to understand how I can initialize a variable and keep track if it. In this program, I have a variable called **number** that I'm initializing at the beginning of the prog and a function at the end. How can I keep the value of **number** that I have in the function until it reaches the button because now, each time that I'm running the program, I got the value from the initialization and not the one from the function. If somebody can explain me how it works, it will be very helpful.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var number = Int()
    var points = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var calc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!                
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!        
    
    @IBAction func add(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if sender.tag == number {
        print("Yes!")
            points += 1
            calc.text = String(points)
        }
        
        else {
            print ("no!")
            points -= 1
            calc.text = String(points)
            
        }
        add ()
    }
   

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         
        add ()
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }    
    
    func add () {
        
        var  number = Int.random(in: 0..<2)
        print(number)
        
        
        if number == 0 {
            
            button1.setTitle("click", for: .normal)
            button2.setTitle("don't click", for: .normal)             
            
        }
        
        else {
            button1.setTitle("don't click", for: .normal)
            button2.setTitle("click", for: .normal)
            
        }   
    }        
}
```

Comment: You should assign to the number that declared out of function. Just remove `var ` in  add method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `var` inside add() in your codes

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var number = Int()
    var points = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var calc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!                
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!        
    
    @IBAction func add(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if sender.tag == number {
        print("Yes!")
            points += 1
            calc.text = String(points)
        }
        
        else {
            print ("no!")
            points -= 1
            calc.text = String(points)
            
        }
        add ()
    }
   

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         
        add ()
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }    
    
    func add () {
        
       // HERE
        self.number = Int.random(in: 0..<2)
        print(number)
        
        
        if number == 0 {
            
            button1.setTitle("click", for: .normal)
            button2.setTitle("don't click", for: .normal)             
            
        }
        
        else {
            button1.setTitle("don't click", for: .normal)
            button2.setTitle("click", for: .normal)
            
        }   
    }        
}
```